# When using CDK and a docker image, cache pip dependencies between PythonFunction builds?

Tags: python, docker, aws-cdk

The issue I'm facing is similar to https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9406 but the resolution to that seems? to just be to use a layer.

I have about 75 Python Lambda functions which I'm deploying using CDK. The functions have a mix of dependencies from both requirements.txt and some private libraries which I copy into the directory (entry). For any functions which have changed cdk does indeed detect the change and goes ahead and spins up a docker image to run pip and do its thing, but doesn't seem to leverage any caching between function builds.

So if I change some piece of code in a base dependency (which all 75 functions depend on), then run cdk deploy, it will spin up docker and run a pip install 75 separate times. Each time pip runs it's pulling down all of the dependencies from scratch. So that's 75 times downloading requests and boto3 and everything else I depend on.

Is there a mechanism for me to share the dependencies between instances of docker spinning up?

For reference, the PythonFunction code: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-python-alpha.PythonFunction.html)

```
        lambdas = {}
        for this_lambda in lambda_details:
            handler = _lambda.PythonFunction(
                self,
                this_lambda[0],
                entry=this_lambda[3],
                index=this_lambda[1],
                handler=this_lambda[2],
                runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
                architecture=Architecture.ARM_64,
                bundling={
                    'image': DockerImage('public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9:latest-arm64'),
                    'asset_hash_type': AssetHashType.SOURCE
                }
            )
            lambdas[this_lambda[0]] = handler
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just using the layers approach. I create one 'common' layer with most of my utility code in it, and then a couple of other layers (which come with a big dependency tree each) that are only used in a couple of places.

When building, if some common code has changed, it'll rebuild the common layer, and then update the various functions which depend on it. If I update just an individual function, just that function gets updated.

I don't like having lots of stuff bundled into a 'common' layer, but having said that it's working pretty well for me.